# Access Javascript file in Kotlin/JS

Tags: javascript, kotlin-js, kotlin-js-interop

I have a bunch of Javascript files I need to access from Kotlin Code.

I created a js-files directory in my root project with the needed .js files and a package.json which looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "js-files",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

My build.gradle looks like this:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("js")
}

version = "unspecified"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    js {
        useCommonJs()

        nodejs()
        browser {
            webpackTask {
                output.libraryTarget = "commonjs2"
            }
        }

        binaries.executable()
    }
}

dependencies {
    val path = rootProject.projectDir.resolve("js-files").canonicalPath
    implementation(npm("js-files", "file:$path"))
}
```

The idea for this I got from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68305290/5608927).

For debugging, i have the following js file in js-files:

```js
export function func() {
    console.log("This is my test function.")
}
```

and my kotlin main looks like this:

```kotlin
@JsModule("js-files")
external fun func()

fun main() {
    func()
}
```

However, when i run the project using vrowserDevelopmentRun i receive this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'js-files' in 'path-to-my-project/build/js/packages/project-name-js/kotlin-dce-dev'
```

Maybe there is an easier way of binding my js files but after hours of research i found nothing. I'm thankful for any help.